# Message Digest in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

as I'm a newbie in this field the question may seem to be so stupid, but please forgive me. I want to achieve SHA-512 in Objective-C for an equivalent Java code..Here is the Java Code  :

```
String passwordSalt = "Somesalt";
byte[] bsalt=base64ToByte(passwordSalt);
byte[] passwordToDigestAsBytes=("somepassword").getBytes("UTF-8");

MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-512");
digest.reset();
digest.update(bsalt);
byte[] = input digest.digest(passwordToDigestAsBytes);
```

I'm using CC_SHA512 for digest function...but what I need to do for digest.update(bsalt) part? how can I achieve the same functionality in Objective-C?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Objective C SHA512 hash of two NSData](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5632632/objective-c-sha512-hash-of-two-nsdata)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Java's `MessageDigest` object, but it looks like it's just prepending the salt before the data, which is a very normal way to process this kind of data. So you'd just call `CC_SHA512_Update()` twice. Once with the salt, and then a second time with the password data. Then you'd call `CC_SHA512_Final()` to fetch the result.